# Drop rows after criteria

Tags: r, rows, data-cleaning

I have some data that I'm trying to clean up, and I noticed that I have 150 files that have rows that are subsets of previous rows.  Is there a way that I can drop everything after certain criteria occur?  Below I'm not sure how I'd write out sample data for this via code, so I've listed an example of the data as text.  Below.  I'd like to drop all rows at and below "section 2"

```
Name,Age,Address
Section 1,,
Abby,10,1 Baker St
Alice,12,3 Main St
Becky,13,156 F St
Ben,14,2 18th St
Cameron,15,4 Journey Road
Danny,16,123 North Ave
Eric,17,325 Hill Blvd
,,
Section 2,,
Abby,10,1 Baker St
Alice,12,3 Main St
Becky,13,156 F St
Ben,14,2 18th St
,,
Section 3,,
Becky,13,156 F St
Ben,14,2 18th St
Cameron,15,4 Journey Road
Danny,16,123 North Ave
,,
Section 5,,
Alice,12,3 Main St
Becky,13,156 F St
Ben,14,2 18th St
Cameron,15,4 Journey Road
Danny,16,123 North Ave
Eric,17,325 Hill Blvd
```

Expected output

```
Name,Age,Address
Section 1,,
Abby,10,1 Baker St
Alice,12,3 Main St
Becky,13,156 F St
Ben,14,2 18th St
Cameron,15,4 Journey Road
Danny,16,123 North Ave
Eric,17,325 Hill Blvd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your text file is called `temp.txt` you can use `readLines` to read it in, find the line with `'Section 2'` in it and read all the lines above that.

```
tmp <- readLines('temp.txt')
inds <- grep('Section 2', tmp) - 2
data <- read.csv(text = paste0(tmp[1:inds], collapse = '\n'))
data
#       Name Age        Address
#1 Section 1  NA               
#2      Abby  10     1 Baker St
#3     Alice  12      3 Main St
#4     Becky  13       156 F St
#5       Ben  14      2 18th St
#6   Cameron  15 4 Journey Road
#7     Danny  16  123 North Ave
#8      Eric  17  325 Hill Blvd
```

Comment: I get this error when I run your code.  Error in 1:inds : argument of length 0

Comment: Did you replace 'temp.txt' with your filename? Can you share `dput(head(tmp, 10))`

Comment: I got it to work!  I restarted the session and it ran without any changes.

Comment: Yes.  Sorry about that,  I came back to reference it and the check mark wasn't green so I clicked on it.  Should be fixed now.  Thank you!

Comment: I ran into another minor issue.  `data <- read.csv(text = paste0(tmp[1:inds], collapse = '\n'))` changes spaces and special characters in my headers to “.”, and in my actual data I’m using a gather function and need to drop everything after a special character.  EX.  `Made U. Name (Age)` becomes `Made.U..Name..Age.`.  Do you now of a way to counteract that?  I'd use gsub, but I only need to drop everything after the second ".."

Comment: R discourages column names to have spaces or to have special characters hence those are changed to '.'. If you still want to use them as name add `check.names = FALSE` in `read.csv`.  `data <- read.csv(text = paste0(tmp[1:inds], collapse = '\n'), check.names = FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

Here, I "read" in your data by calling `strsplit` and using the newline as the separator. If you were doing this from file, you could use `readLines`

I use `grep` to find the line number that contains "Section 2", use that to subset `raw_data`. I `paste0(..., collapse="")` the lines that do not start with "Section" and use `read.table` using `sep=","` with `header=TRUE` to parse as if I read just that section with `read.csv`.

```r
raw_data <- strsplit(split = "\\n", "Name,Age,Address
                  Section 1,,
                  Abby,10,1 Baker St
                  Alice,12,3 Main St
                  Becky,13,156 F St
                  Ben,14,2 18th St
                  Cameron,15,4 Journey Road
                  Danny,16,123 North Ave
                  Eric,17,325 Hill Blvd
                  ,,
                  Section 2,,
                  Abby,10,1 Baker St
                  Alice,12,3 Main St
                  Becky,13,156 F St
                  Ben,14,2 18th St
                  ,,
                  Section 3,,
                  Becky,13,156 F St
                  Ben,14,2 18th St
                  Cameron,15,4 Journey Road
                  Danny,16,123 North Ave
                  ,,
                  Section 5,,
                  Alice,12,3 Main St
                  Becky,13,156 F St
                  Ben,14,2 18th St
                  Cameron,15,4 Journey Road
                  Danny,16,123 North Ave
                  Eric,17,325 Hill Blvd")

section2_idx <- grep('Section 2', raw_data[[1]])

raw_data_clean <- trimws(raw_data[[1]][1:(section2_idx-2)])

allsect_idx <- grep('^Section', raw_data_clean)

if(length(allsect_idx > 0)) 
   raw_data_clean <- raw_data_clean[-allsect_idx]

read.table(text = paste0(raw_data_clean, collapse="\n"), sep=",", header = TRUE)

#>      Name Age        Address
#> 1    Abby  10     1 Baker St
#> 2   Alice  12      3 Main St
#> 3   Becky  13       156 F St
#> 4     Ben  14      2 18th St
#> 5 Cameron  15 4 Journey Road
#> 6   Danny  16  123 North Ave
#> 7    Eric  17  325 Hill Blvd
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a made up example that avoids having to type in your starting data.

mixed_data is 500 elements long and each row is a string containing two commas. The string doesn't need to be broken apart if if looks like your example.

Create an empty vector to hold just one of each value. Then loop through the whole mixed list and add the unique entries to that vector. This example resulted in 444 unique items in  one_of_each of the original 500 in mixed_data.

```
set.seed(101)

a <- sample(LETTERS,500, replace = TRUE)
b <- sample(letters,500, replace = TRUE)
d <- sample(c(1:3),500, replace = TRUE)

mixed_data <- paste0(a,",",b,",",d)
head(mixed_data)

one_of_each <- c()  #starts empty

for (i in 1:length(mixed_data)){
  
  if (mixed_data[i] %in% one_of_each == FALSE) { 
    one_of_each <- c(one_of_each,mixed_data[i])  #if not found, then add
  }
  
}
```